# failed to set the password using the given URL when using docker to create admin

Tags: mongodb, docker

I was just trying to install a local version of sharelatex using this tutorial: [Sharelatex Local Version installation Quick Start Guide](https://github.com/sharelatex/sharelatex/wiki/Quick-Start-Guide)

And I use mongoDB 2.8 and latest version of redis so that the dependencies are met.

Now I could load the login webpage of the sharelatex on http://localhost:5000 
as follows:
[image]

However when I tried to set admin using this command:

```
$ docker exec sharelatex /bin/bash -c "cd /var/www/sharelatex; grunt user:create-admin --email joe@example.com"
```

and I successfully get the following sentence:

> Successfully created joe@example.com as an admin user.
>
> Please visit the following URL to set a password for joe@example.com
>   and log in:
>
> http://localhost/user/password/set?passwordResetToken=a3f326880969c7a1b7e4aad7b2369fb0157f3b5688d6540769ce78203f5650b8

I could not load the corresponding webpage.

May I know what is my problem?

Comment: Would the same url at http://localhost:5000/... work?

Comment: it works now! thank you very much!

Comment: Thank you. Don't forget to review your past question and see if their answers can be accepted as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering you were accessing the original url on port 5000, it stands to reason you would keep that same port.

http://localhost:5000/user/password/set?passwordResetToken=a3f32688...

If Docker [exposes the port 5000](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#/expose-incoming-ports) (with `docker run -d -v ~/sharelatex_data:/var/lib/sharelatex -p 5000:80`), that port would be needed for *all* http requests.